# Phonegap media api pause/resume

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am creating an RSS player app with phonegap. Everything is working apart from the pause/resume function. Pausing is fine but when pressing the pause button again (to resume playback) it goes back to the start of the mp3. My code is below. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
        //window.alert("Loading PhoneGap is completed");
    }

    var media = null;
    var mediaTimer = null;

    function playAudio() {

        //get url passed from previous screen.
        var mp3 = localStorage.getItem("url_to_play");
        var src = mp3;

        media = new Media (src , onSuccess, onError);

        //Play the audio. You can set number of the replaying time here.
        media.play({numberOfLoops:"infinite"});

        if (mediaTimer == null) {

            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {

                // Return a current playback position
                media.getCurrentPosition(

                    //A Callback function if it's success
                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                            setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");

                                    //If the playback stops at "-0.001" position, replay the audio.
                                    if(position == -0.001){

                                        media.play({numberOfLoops:"infinite"});

                                    }
                        }
                    },
                    //A callback function in case of failure
                    function(e) {

                        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);

                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }



    }

    function pauseAudio() {

        if (media) {
            media.pause();
        }
    }

    function stopAudio() {

        if (media) {
            media.stop();
        }

        clearInterval(mediaTimer);
        mediaTimer = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sorted this by doing the following:

```
if(media === null){media = new Media (src , onSuccess, onError);}
```

Only create the new media object if it doesn't exist. If it does exist then its already playing and doesn't need this.